# Android: how to solve OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, out-of-memory, png, horizontalscrollview, nestedscrollview

I am using an `NestedScrollView` for my layout to display a `TextView` as a header with a `HorizontalScrollView` to display slidable pictures.
Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_weight="1">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Cable Crunches"
            android:id="@+id/cableCrunches"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cableCrunches"
            android:id="@+id/cableCrunchesPics">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/cableCrunchesPics1"
                    android:src="@drawable/cable_crunches_1"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/cableCrunchesPics2"
                    android:src="@drawable/cable_crunches_2"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/cableCrunchesPics3"
                    android:src="@drawable/cable_crunches_3"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/cableCrunchesPics4"
                    android:src="@drawable/cable_crunches_4"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/cableCrunchesPics5"
                    android:src="@drawable/cable_crunches_5"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The `TextView` and the `HorizontalScrollView` block are used around 15 times in my layout and with this design I've got a OutOfMemoryError.
When I use less of those blocks the error doesn´t appear.

I've tried to minimize the size of my PNG files, but this doesn't solve the problem.
Is there any other layout I could use were not all `ImageView` are loaded at the start of the app?

Comment: Use picasso library to show images in your layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) or [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) with `ImageView` as row item instead of `HorizontalScrollView`. `RecyclerView` will create enough `ImageView`s to fill the screen. When the user scrolls it will reuse the existing `ImageView`'s.

Also consider using an image loading library to load the images asynchronously. [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) are really good libraries.

Comment: There are also nice tutorials for that: [picasso](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/android-recyclerview-and-picasso-tutorial.html)   [glide](http://blog.grafixartist.com/image-gallery-app-android-studio-1-4-glide/)

Comment: Thanks I use now a RecyclerView! :D

Comment: @LarsH. you are welcome. If this answer solves your problem you can accept it using the check-mark below answer score.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your manifest in application tag

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
```

Maybe this will help you

And yes like others said. You can use different libraries to load images. I would recommend Universal image Loader. [Link](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: This doesn't solve the OutOfMemoryError bug, all it means it will take a little while longer to run into the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

you could use an library for loading the images. My favourite one is Glide 
it is simple to use https://github.com/bumptech/glide.

So you would load your images programmatically. You also gain more control over the how, when and where to load images. Glide also solved some memory issues in my App.